# LSTM cell output activation for series

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, tensorflow

This question is asked from the perspective of finding out if there's a more efficient way for an LSTM to act more as a regression entity rather than just assigning only probabilities to the next character.

In general a seq2seq LSTM char generator will act mainly as such:

```
C H A P T -> E
H A P T E -> R
```

That's great. What if I want to assign a numerical series that don't show only a probability of the next number but rather contain a regression function such as `f(x) = 2x² + 3`. Or maybe containing more `f(x)`s that describe such series i.e.

```
1 3 5 7 -> 9
3 5 7 9 -> 11
```

My question: Should I find a way to change the activation function of each LSTM cell (normally it's `tanh`) with another activation function that can at the same time preserves the probability of the  next character and somehow preserve or "understands" that there is a regression of numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform regression with a recurrent neural network (RNN), people typically add a dense layer after the RNN layer, taking the RNN hidden state as input. As a result, the traditional LSTM with tanh followed by a dense layer works: it won't only predict values between -1 and 1.

Examples:

- http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/
- http://mourafiq.com/2016/05/15/predicting-sequences-using-rnn-in-tensorflow.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in the second link, we can technically say that the LSTM is able to "generate" a sine wave? (I'm more interested in generation rather than prediction)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a dense layer is needed? Why isn't a linear combination of the hidden activations sufficient?

Comment: @ValentinIovene, from what I've seen a linear combination of hidden activations is fine for certain cases. For instance, this tutorial from Jason Brownlee shows using a Dense(1) layer right above the LSTM and then using it as the model output (without activation), which is the linear combination you described. https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/